# K2: Show 5 articles per page

Tags: joomla-3.x, k2

I have created a `Categories` menu item and wants to show only 5 articles per page. But can't find the option to add the limit in K2 component.

Kindly, let me know where I can change this limit for pagination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

- Go to **Components** > **K2** > **Categories**

Here select the main category and go to the Tab **Display Settings**, see the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: thank you but setting leading count means the number of leading articles to show. By setting 5, five leading articles are shown in the page plus the rest of the primary articles. I want to display only 5 articles per page. Sadly, didn't work

Comment: Just change the other values to 0.

Comment: perfectly worked! thanks a lot Alex . upvoted and accepted :)